# R: Optimizing "Overlap Calculations"

Tags: r

Using R, I tried to create these two random shapefiles that represent two sets of "zones" within some city:

```
set.seed(123)
# Load the ggplot2 and sf packages
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

# Set the longitude and latitude for New York
lon_1 <- -74.0060
lat_1 <- 40.7128

# Set the longitude and latitude for a second location
lon_2 <- -74.037
lat_2 <- 40.733

# Set the size of the square
size <- 0.1

# Create a square centered on New York
square_1 <- st_sfc(st_polygon(list(rbind(
    c(lon_1 - size/2, lat_1 - size/2),
    c(lon_1 + size/2, lat_1 - size/2),
    c(lon_1 + size/2, lat_1 + size/2),
    c(lon_1 - size/2, lat_1 + size/2),
    c(lon_1 - size/2, lat_1 - size/2)
))))

# Create a square centered on New York
square_2 <- st_sfc(st_polygon(list(rbind(
    c(lon_2 - size/2, lat_2 - size/2),
    c(lon_2 + size/2, lat_2 - size/2),
    c(lon_2 + size/2, lat_2 + size/2),
    c(lon_2 - size/2, lat_2 + size/2),
    c(lon_2 - size/2, lat_2 - size/2)
))))



# Set the number of mini rectangles
n <- 4

# Create random mini rectangles within the square
mini_rectangles_1 <- vector("list", n)
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    x1 <- runif(1, lon_1 - size/2, lon_1)
    x2 <- runif(1, lon_1, lon_1 + size/2)
    y1 <- runif(1, lat_1 - size/2, lat_1)
    y2 <- runif(1, lat_1, lat_1 + size/2)
    mini_rectangles_1[[i]] <- st_polygon(list(rbind(
        c(x1, y1),
        c(x2, y1),
        c(x2,y2),
        c(x1,y2),
        c(x1,y1)
    )))
}
mini_rectangles_1 <- st_sfc(mini_rectangles_1)


mini_rectangles_2 <- vector("list", n)
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    x1 <- runif(1, lon_2 - size/2, lon_2)
    x2 <- runif(1, lon_2, lon_2 + size/2)
    y1 <- runif(1,lat_2 - size/2,lat_2)
    y2 <- runif(1,lat_2,lat_2 + size/2)
    mini_rectangles_2[[i]] <- st_polygon(list(rbind(
        c(x1,y1),
        c(x2,y1),
        c(x2,y2),
        c(x1,y2),
        c(x1,y1)
    )))
}


mini_rectangles_2 <- st_sfc(mini_rectangles_2)
```

I then tried to visualize the results:

```
# Plot the squares and the mini rectangles
ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = st_sf(square_1), fill = "white", color = "black") +
    geom_sf(data = st_sf(square_2), fill = "white", color = "black") +
    geom_sf(data = st_sf(mini_rectangles_1), fill = "red", color = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_sf(data = st_sf(mini_rectangles_2), fill = "blue", color = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(min(lon_1 - size*0.6, lon_2 - size*0.6), max(lon_1 + size*0.6, lon_2 + size*0.6)), ylim = c(min(lat_1 - size*0.6, lat_2 - size*0.6), max(lat_1 + size*0.6, lat_2 + size*0.6)))
```

[image]

**My Question:** I am now interested in determining what percent of each red square is covered by each blue square and what percent of each blue square is covered by each red square

I tried to find some similar questions e.g. [How to compute all pairwise interaction between polygons and the the percentage coverage in R with sf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70009412/how-to-compute-all-pairwise-interaction-between-polygons-and-the-the-percentage) - based on these references, I then tried to modify the code to suit my requirements:

```
# Create a 4x4 matrix to store coverage percentages
n = 4
coverage_matrix <- matrix(0,n,n)

# Calculate coverage percentages for each pair of red and blue rectangles
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    for (j in seq_len(n)) {
        intersection_area <- st_area(st_intersection(mini_rectangles_1[[i]], mini_rectangles_2[[j]]))
        red_area <- st_area(mini_rectangles_1[[i]])
        coverage_matrix[i,j] <- 100 * intersection_area / red_area
    }
}

# Print coverage matrix
print(coverage_matrix)


rownames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("Red ", seq_len(n))
colnames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("Blue ", seq_len(n))

# Print the modified coverage matrix
print(coverage_matrix)
```

The final result looks something like this:

```
        Blue 1   Blue 2    Blue 3    Blue 4
Red 1  0.00000  0.00000  1.696167 16.371502
Red 2  0.00000  0.00000 23.741099 26.089504
Red 3 81.49752 19.38099 21.055805 47.402298
Red 4 28.27181  0.00000  0.000000  3.646122
```

**Assuming I have done this correctly - I am trying to figure out a way to improve the speed of this code.** In real life, I have multiple blue squares and multiple red squares (e.g. over 1000) and the code I have written is taking a very long time to run. As such, I am looking for ways to improve the efficiency and run-time of my code.

**Can someone please show me how to do this?**

**References:**

- [How to compute all pairwise interaction between polygons and the the percentage coverage in R with sf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70009412/how-to-compute-all-pairwise-interaction-between-polygons-and-the-the-percentage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little helper function is in order to find the areas of the intersecting
regions and return them in a matrix. `st_intersection()` is vectorised to
find the intersection geometries, but the result doesn’t maintain information
about which of the input geometries form the resulting intersection, so we
get that from `st_intersects()`:

```r
st_intersection_area <- function(x, y) {
  area <- st_area(st_intersection(x, y))
  intersects <- as.matrix(st_intersects(x, y))
  replace(intersects, which(intersects), area)
}
```

Now the question can be solved as follows:

```r
area_r <- st_area(mini_rectangles_1)
area_b <- st_area(mini_rectangles_2)

st_intersection_area(mini_rectangles_1, mini_rectangles_2) / area_r
#>            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
#> [1,] 0.06997851 0.2976404 0.3385203 0.05587322
#> [2,] 0.00000000 0.6214937 0.6921818 0.00000000
#> [3,] 0.00000000 0.4742746 0.5933578 0.00000000
#> [4,] 0.00000000 0.2101857 0.2431918 0.00000000
st_intersection_area(mini_rectangles_2, mini_rectangles_1) / area_b
#>           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#> [1,] 0.1195645 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> [2,] 0.6054833 0.08194228 0.1960124 0.3108706
#> [3,] 0.6773595 0.08976680 0.2412096 0.3537933
#> [4,] 0.1533763 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

To add progress indicators or to parallelize,
use a loop and batch the inputs.

```r
batch <- function(x, size) {
  (seq_along(x) - 1) %/% size
}

rect_1 <- make_rect(n = 400)
rect_2 <- make_rect(n = 400)

rect_2_batch <- split(rect_2, batch(rect_2, size = 100))
system.time({
  area_i <- do.call(cbind, purrr::map(rect_2_batch, function(x) {
    st_intersection_area(rect_1, x)
  }, .progress = "Calculating intersection area..."))
})
#> Calculating intersection area... ■■■■■■■■■ 25% | ETA: …Calculating intersection
#> area... ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 50% | ETA: …Calculating intersection area...
#> ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 75% | ETA: …
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    4.41    0.07    4.50
```

(Note that this is now very similar to some of your previous approaches,
but the additional use of `st_intersects()` makes sure we get the correct
results when there are empty intersections.)

Comment: @ Mikko Marttila: Thank you so much for your answer! Do you think your answer will run faster than mine for larger datasets?

Comment: @stats_noob I tested your example with n = 100 and ended up with 9.2 s using the loop in your question and 0.3 s using my answer. So yes, I'd expect this to scale quite a bit better.

Comment: @ Mikko: Thank you so much! the code you wrote: st_intersection_area(mini_rectangles_1, mini_rectangles_2) / area_r .... seems to be giving the same results as mine!

Comment: @ Mikko: I timed the differences in both approaches on my own computer. here are the results: Your Approach: Time difference of 0.2654738 secs .... My Approach: Time difference of 0.004674911 secs

Comment: @ Mikko Marttila: is it somehow possible to add a "print" statement to this code to see how much progress has been made?

Comment: Not directly. You could batch the inputs to add a loop in which you could print progress steps, but that will cost you a bit of performance due to the extra function calls. In this case that's probably warranted for a long running task though, as if done sparingly the printouts can clarify what's going on even if not printed very often. That's basically your Approach 1, but with correct output.

Comment: @ Mikko Marttila: Thank you so much for your update! Currently, I am trying to figure out if there is a way to add row names and column names to the matrix produced in your answer

Comment: Just to clarify: # red square covering blue square
    st_intersection_area(mini_rectangles_1, mini_rectangles_2) / area_r

Comment: #blue square covering red square
    st_intersection_area(mini_rectangles_2, mini_rectangles_1) / area_b

Comment: You can of course set dimension names like with any other matrix. Looks like you got the proportion interpretations mixed up.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please show me how to correct this just to make sure?

Comment: If you divide the intersection area by the area of the red square, you get the proportion of the red square covered by (not _covering_) the blue square, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some different approaches I tried - however, I am not sure if these are really helping?:

**Note: Some of these approaches produce numbers that are quite wrong!**

**Approach 1:** Single Loop

```
coverage_matrix <- matrix(0, n, n)

for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  intersection_areas <- st_area(st_intersection(mini_rectangles_1[i], mini_rectangles_2))
  red_areas <- st_area(mini_rectangles_1[i])
  coverage_matrix[i, ] <- 100 * intersection_areas / red_areas
}


rownames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("Red ", seq_len(n))
colnames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("Blue ", seq_len(n))

print(coverage_matrix)
```

**Approach 2:** mcapply

```
library(parallel)

coverage_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)

calculate_coverage <- function(i) {
    intersection_areas <- mclapply(seq_len(n), function(j) {
        st_area(st_intersection(mini_rectangles_1[[i]], mini_rectangles_2[[j]]))
    })
    red_areas <- st_area(mini_rectangles_1[[i]])
    100 * sapply(intersection_areas, sum) / red_areas
}

# do I need an mc.cores statement here?
coverage_list <- mclapply(seq_len(n), calculate_coverage)

coverage_matrix <- matrix(unlist(coverage_list), nrow = n, ncol = n, byrow = TRUE)


rownames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("Red ", seq_len(n))
colnames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("Blue ", seq_len(n))


print(coverage_matrix)
```

**Approach 3: lapply**

```
coverage_matrix <- matrix(0, n, n)

calculate_coverage <- function(i) {
  intersection_areas <- st_area(st_intersection(mini_rectangles_1[i], mini_rectangles_2))
  red_areas <- st_area(mini_rectangles_1[i])
  100 * intersection_areas / red_areas
}

coverage_list <- lapply(seq_len(n), calculate_coverage)

coverage_matrix <- do.call(rbind, coverage_list)



rownames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("Red ", seq_len(n))
colnames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("Blue ", seq_len(n))

print(coverage_matrix)
```

**Approach 4:** dopar

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

num_cores <- parallel::detectCores()

cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

clusterEvalQ(cl, {
    library(sf)
})

coverage_matrix <- matrix(0, n, n)

calculate_coverage <- function(i) {
    library(sf)  
    intersection_areas <- sf::st_area(sf::st_intersection(mini_rectangles_1[i], mini_rectangles_2))
    red_areas <- sf::st_area(mini_rectangles_1[i])
    100 * intersection_areas / red_areas
}

coverage_list <- foreach(i = seq_len(n), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    calculate_coverage(i)
}

stopCluster(cl)

coverage_matrix[] <- coverage_list

rownames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("Red ", seq_len(n))
colnames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("Blue ", seq_len(n))

print(coverage_matrix)
```

**Approach 5:** Functional Approach (numbers look really wrong)

```
library(sf)

calculate_coverage_vectorized <- function(mini_rectangles_1, mini_rectangles_2) {


  intersection_areas <- sf::st_area(sf::st_intersection(mini_rectangles_1, mini_rectangles_2))
  
  intersection_areas[is.na(intersection_areas)] <- 0
  

  red_areas <- sf::st_area(mini_rectangles_1)
  
  # Calculate the coverage percentages
  coverage_percentages <- 100 * intersection_areas / red_areas
  
  return(coverage_percentages)
}

coverage_list <- calculate_coverage_vectorized(mini_rectangles_1, mini_rectangles_2)

coverage_matrix[] <- coverage_list

rownames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("Red ", seq_len(n))
colnames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("Blue ", seq_len(n))

print(coverage_matrix)
```

**References:**

- [R: Improving the Speed of Pairwise Calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76301483/r-improving-the-speed-of-pairwise-calculations)
- [R: Understanding the Difference Between Different Parallel Computing Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74780793/r-understanding-the-difference-between-different-parallel-computing-options)

Comment: As `st_intersection()` returns only non-empty intersection geometries, most of these approaches produce an incorrect result.

Comment: @  Mikko Marttila: Thank you for your reply! Yes, I agree! I have noticed that the numbers in some of these approaches seem to be quite wrong :(